# Wireguard - unable to use wired interface

Tags: wireguard

I've configured wireguard server and client to work using the wifi interface (wlan). When plugging into my router via a cable, i'm unable to establish a connection/handshake on connected interface eth0.

How do i allow both interfaces to work (i want the flexibility to switch between the two)?

```
pi@metalhead_4:~/configs $ cat wguardvpn.conf 
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.226.150.3/24,fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::3/64
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 149.112.112.112

#PreUp   = iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --jump MASQUERADE --out interface eth0 
#PreUp   = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE -o wg0
PreUp   = iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 10.226.0.0/24 -o et0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.226.150.3 -t nat
#PreDown   = iptables --table nat --delete POSTROUTING --jump MASQUERADE --out interface eth0 
#PreDown   = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE -o wg0
PreDown   = iptables -D POSTROUTING -s 10.226.0.0/24 -o et0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.226.150.3 -t nat

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
PresharedKey =
Endpoint = 67.170.120.108:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
```

pi@metalhead_4:~ $ sudo wg

```
interface: wg0
  public key: 
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer:
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 67.170.120.108:51407
  allowed ips: 10.226.150.3/32, fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::3/128
  latest handshake: 1 hour, 41 minutes, 53 seconds ago
  transfer: 7.00 MiB received, 145.60 MiB sent

peer:
  preshared key: (hidden)
  allowed ips: 10.226.150.2/32, fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::2/128
```

pi@metalhead_4:~ $ ifconfig

```
    eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.49.217.61  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.49.217.255
    inet6 fe80::d506:9085:74d0:2b8a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2601:602:8e80:b240:4968:d21a:4abc:fc6d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 2601:602:8e80:b240::e064  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether b8:27:eb:1b:21:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1995  bytes 428128 (418.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5830  bytes 515199 (503.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 52001  bytes 5167821 (4.9 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 52001  bytes 5167821 (4.9 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    wg0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
    inet 10.226.150.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 
    10.226.150.1
    inet6 fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 57864  bytes 7337748 (6.9 MiB)
    RX errors 12  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 12
    TX packets 110029  bytes 149649588 (142.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 2110 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::484d:7bce:4a83:643a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2601:602:8e80:b240:8a70:b1dc:4722:ae87  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 2601:602:8e80:b240::ffe5  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether b8:27:eb:4e:74:1e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 447644  bytes 226415651 (215.9 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 430179  bytes 228344598 (217.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

IPTables

```
    pi@metalhead_4:~ $ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:51820 /* wireguard-input-rule */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:51820 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.200.200.0/24      anywhere             tcp dpt:domain ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.226.150.0/24      anywhere             tcp dpt:domain ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  10.226.150.0/24      anywhere             udp dpt:domain ctstate NEW

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.226.150.0/24      ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* wireguard-forward-rule */
ACCEPT     all  --  10.226.150.0/24      anywhere             /* wireguard-forward-rule */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Please provide better context for your question. Where is this server set up on and where are you connecting from? Are you using the VPN *within* the same / your home network or what?

Comment: Server is setup in my home network. I'm currently testing and connecting from w/in my home network as well. I will eventually be connecting from outside of my home network.